# How to Crop a cuda.GpuMat in GoCV (opencv 4)?

Tags: opencv, go

I am using GoCV (Open CV 4 bindings for go) and I want to crop an image represented as a `cuda.GpuMat` given an `image.Rectangle`.

With a regular `gocv.Mat` this operation is simple enough:

```
func Crop(src *gocv.Mat, rect image.Rectangle) *gocv.Mat {
    res := src.Region(rect)
    return &res
}
```

However, I do not see a similar `Region` method on the `cuda.GpuMat` in GoCv (some bindings are not implemented yet), nor do I see a `region` method in the C++ source/docs: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d60/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1GpuMat.html.

I have managed to effectively crop using `cuda.Remap` as follows:

```
func Crop(src *cuda.GpuMat, rect image.Rectangle) *cuda.GpuMat {
    rectWidth := rect.Dx()
    rectHeight := rect.Dy()

    dst := cuda.NewGpuMat()
    map1 := gocv.NewMatWithSize(rectHeight, rectWidth, gocv.MatTypeCV32F)
    defer map1.Close()
    map2 := gocv.NewMatWithSize(rectHeight, rectWidth, gocv.MatTypeCV32F)
    defer map2.Close()

    offsetX := rect.Min.X
    offsetY := rect.Min.Y
    for x := 0; x < map1.Cols(); x++ {
        for y := 0; y < map2.Rows(); y++ {
            map1.SetFloatAt(x, y, float32(y+offsetY))
            map2.SetFloatAt(x, y, float32(x+offsetX))
        }
    }

    gmap1, gmap2 := cuda.NewGpuMat(), cuda.NewGpuMat()
    defer gmap1.Close()
    defer gmap2.Close()
    gmap1.Upload(map1)
    gmap2.Upload(map2)
    cuda.Remap(*src, &dst, &gmap1, &gmap2, cuda.InterpolationDefault, cuda.BorderConstant, color.RGBA{0, 0, 0, 0})
    return &dst
}
```

But after running some benchmarks this implementation is 1-2 orders of magnitude slower than `gocv.Mat#Region`.

Given that there is no `Region` method on `cuda.GpuMat` in GoCV or OpenCV4, what would be the most optimal equivalent operation?

I'm not too concerned if the GoCV bindings do not exist. I'm more interested in the OpenCV4 equivalent to `Region` for a `GpuMat`.

**UPDATE**

I have found another method of cropping a cuda.GpuMat, but it is also about an order of magnitude slower than `gocv.Mat#Region`.

```
func Crop2(src *cuda.GpuMat, rect image.Rectangle) *cuda.GpuMat {
    rectWidth := rect.Dx()
    rectHeight := rect.Dy()
    dst := cuda.NewGpuMat()
    sz := image.Point{
        X: rectWidth,
        Y: rectHeight,
    }
    cuda.Rotate(*src, &dst, sz, 0, -float64(rect.Min.X), -float64(rect.Min.Y), cuda.InterpolationDefault)
    return &dst
}
```